# dateutil parser unable to parse dd mm yyyy

Tags: python, cx-oracle, python-dateutil

I am trying to parse a date string field in an Oracle table using cx_Oracle and dateutil parser. In the DEV environment, strings that are formatted dd mm yyyy are failing to parse, while in PROD environment, this works fine. Using same database in each (Oracle 11g). The version of cx_Oracle is the only difference. This hits me as a problem with some kind of environment setting. Any ideas for what I should look for and how?

DEV environment:
os: windows server 2008 r2 standard sp1
python: version 2.7.5
dateutil: version 2.7.3
cx_Oracle: version 6.3.1

PROD environment:
os: windows server 2008 r2 standard sp1
python: version 2.7.5
dateutil: version 2.7.3
cx_Oracle: version 5.1.2

Comment: You can either downgrade `cx_Oracle` version in your `dev` env or you can somehow update it in `prod` env

Comment: Is the parsing something that `cx_Oracle` is doing, or something that you are doing?

Comment: cx_Oracle can accept the dates back from Oracle directly without the need to parse. Why are you parsing? Can you add that information in your question? Also, if you can provide the code and the table structure and data so that I can attempt to replicate your scenario that would be helpful.

Comment: I am using cx_Oracle to query a database table. One field in the table is type string. It holds dates in 4 or 5 different date formats, and cx_Oracle simply returns the field contents.. I use dateutil.parser.parse() method to convert the string to a datetime object. Smells like a default setting somewhere in the tech stack.